# Renaming .met file with ModelBuilder which uses iterator to rename .sid files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, arccatalog, mrsid

[image: iterator for renaming .sid rasters]

I have a model that iterates through a folder containing .sid raster datasets, amongst other types of rasters (so I'm using a *.sid wildcard).

I note, however, that ArcCatalog/ModelBuilder/Rename tool cannot rename the .met file of this .sid dataset, hence the renamed dataset does not have projection information.

Does anyone know how to force ModelBuilder to rename the .met component of a .sid file?

Possibly I'd have to save it as a Python script and add some code to that.

Comment: Could it be as simple as adding multiple wildcard strings?  As in "*.sid; *.met"  It's a shot in the dark but it's what I would try next...  Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thought but nope, I tried that already. I tried just a model with the wildcard set to *.met too, but no luck. I note that .met files are listed in ArcCatalog but right clicking on them the copy/delete/rename options are greyed out.